# How to transform a binary tree into a list in java using stack safe (heap based) recursion?

Tags: java, list, algorithm, binary-tree, tail-recursion

### The question is: How can I implement the method below ( `toListPreOrderLeft`) using tail recursion?

```
 public List<A> toListPreOrderLeft() {
        return toListPreOrderLeft_(this, list()).eval();
    }

    private TailCall<List<A>> toListPreOrderLeft_(TreeNode<A> tree, List<A> list) {
        return ???
    }
```

### Details:

Lets say I have this tree:

[image]

transforming it into a list using pre-order-left algorithm will produce the list : [4,2,1,3,6,5,7]

I could implement this algorithm using stack-recursion in the tree class:

```
 public List<A> toListPreOrderLeft() {
            return list(this.value)
                    .concat(this.left.toListPreOrderLeft())
                    .concat(this.right.toListPreOrderLeft());
        }
```

where `concat` just concatenates two lists, and `this` refers to the tree node on which I am calling the method. 
(I am using my custom implementation of List and Tree).

**But** this implementation will overflow the stack if I have a tree inserted in this order: 100000,99999,99998,99997,...,3,2,1.

Here is the class I use to represent the tail-recursive calls:

```
public abstract class TailCall<T> {

    public abstract TailCall<T> nextCall();

    public abstract T eval();

    public abstract boolean isIntermediate();

    //this constructor is to prevent this class from being extended by other classes
    private TailCall() {
    }

    public static <T> TailCall<T> terminalCall(T t) {
        return new TerminalCall<>(t);
    }

    public static <T> TailCall<T> intermediateCall(Supplier<TailCall<T>> nextCall) {
        return new IntermediateCall<>(nextCall);
    }

    private static class TerminalCall<T> extends TailCall<T> {
        private final T t;

        private TerminalCall(T t) {
            this.t = t;
        }

        @Override
        public T eval() {
            return t;
        }

        @Override
        public TailCall<T> nextCall() {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Terminal has no next call");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isIntermediate() {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static class IntermediateCall<T> extends TailCall<T> {
        private final Supplier<TailCall<T>> nextCall;

        private IntermediateCall(Supplier<TailCall<T>> nextCall) {
            this.nextCall = nextCall;
        }

        @Override
        public T eval() {
            TailCall<T> tailCall = this;
            while (tailCall.isIntermediate()) {
                tailCall = tailCall.nextCall();
            }
            return tailCall.eval();
        }

        @Override
        public TailCall<T> nextCall() {
            return nextCall.get();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isIntermediate() {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is an example of how to implement a method that transforms the tree into a list using in-order traversal and using tail-recursion with this class (we keep rotating the tree until it becomes like an ordered linked list):

```
   public List<A> toListInOrderLeft() {
        return toListInOrderLeft_(this, list()).eval();
    }

    private TailCall<List<A>> toListInOrderLeft_(TreeNode<A> tree, List<A> accumulator) {
        return tree.isEmpty()
                ? TailCall.terminalCall(accumulator)
                : tree.right().isEmpty()
                ? intermediateCall(() -> toListInOrderLeft_(tree.left(), accumulator.prepend(tree.value()))) //prepend adds value at the start of a list
                : intermediateCall(() -> toListInOrderLeft_(tree.rotateLeft(), accumulator));
    }
```

#### Here is a brief explanation of the code in the question:

- `TailCall` is a class that represents a recursive call, so instead of doing a recursive call by pushing a new stackframe, we create an instance of `TailCall` which can be intermediate or terminal subclass depending on whether the recursive call is the last call or there will be a next call embedded in it (in the `TailCall` object) using a Supplier (which achieves lazy evaluation). So at any point in time, we either have 1 **referenced** object representing the whole recursion chain, or at most 2 **referenced** objects representing it (and this latter case happens when we start evaluating the `TailCall`'s next call using `eval` method
- Now that that was said, it is easy to see how the example method `toListInOrderLeft` works, it calls a helper method which returns a `TailCall` (representing the first recursive call) and then calls `eval` on this returned object to evaluate the recursive calls till the end. As for the helper method, it takes an **accumulator** (initially an empty list) and starts appending values to it taken from the tree's nodes. And when the terminal condition is reached, we return this accumulator wrapped in a terminal call from the helper method.

Comment: I'm not going to read all your java code, but a stack is perfect for depth-first-search. Just maintain a stack of nodes to visit. Initially this stack only contains the root. When you visit a node: 1) append its value to the list; 2) push the right child onto the stack; 3) push the left child onto the stack.

Comment: @Stef I am talking about the function-call stack of java which overflows at 1000-3000 calls (aprox), and you are talking about a heap-based stack (one that I create a variable of it myself). Its ok I know I can do this, but I am asking about a heap based method based on tail-recursion, so if you have a way to do it?  I am not asking about the best method, I am asking about this specific method

Comment: What specific method? Of course you can use a tail-recursive function, if for some reason you don't like while-loops. That's just a method for looping. But you're still going to have to store nodes somewhere, and for depth-first-search, a stack is perfect for that.

Comment: the `TailCall` stores a `Supplier` that represents the next recursive call, this is how I am using tail-recursion, If you read the code you see that in the heap-based way which uses `TailCall`, I don't store the nodes and I don't even use a stack

Comment: @Stef I updated the question to make it clear what I want to achieve, if you may have a look again it would be appreciated

Comment: *"heap based"*: this is an ambiguous term when discussing trees. Speak of dynamic allocation instead, since you don't mean the data structure, but the memory pool.

Comment: *"...and I don't even use a stack"*: well, your `TailCall` instances are nodes in a custom-made linked list, which is a way to implement a stack (using heap memory). If that is acceptable to you, then I don't see why creating a stack as suggested above is a no-go.

Comment: @trincot it is because this code is from a book I am reading and I want to know how this can be implemented using their approach, and by "heap based", I mean we are storing the next recursive call in a `Supplier` which will use the heap instead of the normal function call stack which is more limited

Comment: If you want to follow a certain book, of which there is no trace in your question, then you are actually asking us to first get acquainted with that book, and which "rules" you have for a solution. Again, an explicit stack or a class that creates a linked list both use heap memory for the same purpose, so you need to make your question a lot more specific of what exactly your rules are. Just refusing a good idea because it is not like the book you are reading is not really going to make your question popular.

Comment: @trincot I posted the specific code I wanted to use and it seemed that no one is going to be interested in reading all this code, now I updated the question and made it more specific with the code I want

Comment: I am not going to read significant amounts of Java code without [doc comments](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide) or better.

Comment: @greybeard although I think the classes and variables do the same as their names suggest, I will add some documentation at the end of my question to explain more

Comment: @greybeard you can have a look at the updated question and tell me if further explanation is needed

Comment: Not having read any of the previous comments or answers, may I ask if simply keeping a list or stack of parent nodes and left/right flag per recursion level in order to be able to back-track would be an acceptable approach? This way you can iterate over the tree without using recursive method calls. Technically, even that is not strictly necessary, if you know the current tree depth and whether you are right or left. Then you can IMO use that information to track back by looking at previously added elements of your result list. But that would be more complicated to implement.

Comment: @kriegaex I am not looking for the best solution of traversing a tree, I am looking for a solution within my defined classes and methods, so as long as your solution follows what I mentioned in the question then it will answer my specific question

Comment: Well, you just accepted and rewarded an answer suggesting what I also suggested. I agree with the author that (ab)using your tail call class is horrible. The second approach is what I had in mind, minus the possible optimisation of using the result list under construction itself as an element stack. I am happy the problem is solved, I wouldn't have had time to write an answer myself anyway, just found the question interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TailCall` cannot really be used as a stack to remember things.  It can model tail recursion, but the recursive implementation of `toListPreorderLeft` is not just tail recursive.

Many languages provide "monadic" classes similar to `TailCall`, but with something like a `TailCall.then(...)` method that you can use to chain stuff together.  Without this capability, you will need to make another stack -- either explicitly or implicitly.

Your `toListInorderLeft` method has the same problem, but you cheated by mutating the tree, effectively using the tree as your stack.  That trick won't work for preorder.

You *can* solve this problem by translating the recursive algorithm into "continuation passing style".  This implicitly makes a stack of lambda functions:

```
class TreeNode<A> {
    
    TreeNode<A> left;
    TreeNode<A> right;
    A value;

    ...

    public TailCall<List<A>> toListPreOrderLeft() {
        return _toListPreOrderLeft(new ArrayList<>(), null);
    }

    private TailCall<List<A>> _toListPreOrderLeft(List<A> accumulator, Function<List<A>, TailCall<List<A>>> continuation) {
        accumulator.add(this.value);
        if (this.left != null && this.right != null) {
            final Function<List<A>, TailCall<List<A>>> cont2 = (accum) ->
                    this.right._toListPreOrderLeft(accum, continuation);
            return TailCall.intermediateCall(() -> this.left._toListPreOrderLeft(accumulator, cont2));
        } else if (this.right != null) {
            return TailCall.intermediateCall(() -> this.right._toListPreOrderLeft(accumulator, continuation));
        } else if (this.left != null) {
            return TailCall.intermediateCall(() -> this.right._toListPreOrderLeft(accumulator, continuation));
        } else if (continuation != null) {
            return TailCall.intermediateCall(() -> continuation.apply(accumulator));
        }
        return TailCall.terminalCall(accumulator);
    }
}
```

The `continuation` parameter captures the work that remains to be done after the current call ends.  The links from `cont2` to `continuation` form an implicit stack.

Please note that this is a *horrible* way to avoid stack overflows.  It's much better to understand the algorithm and write a nice iterative implementation like this:

```
    public List<A> toListPreOrderLeft() {
        final List<A> accumulator = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<TreeNode<A>> treeStack = new ArrayList<>();
        TreeNode<A> n = this;
        for (;;) {
            accumulator.add(n.value);
            if (n.left != null) {
                if (n.right != null) {
                    treeStack.add((n.right));
                }
                n = n.left;
            } else if (n.right != null) {
                n = n.right;
            } else if (!treeStack.isEmpty()) {
                n = treeStack.remove(treeStack.size()-1);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return accumulator;
    }
```

Comment: I knew I needed another `TailCall` to apply the function recursively to the right branch but didn't know how to do. it,It turns out that functional programming ways can be messy sometimes, thanks.